# UserLoginTask AsyncTask error

Tags: android, api, android-asynctask

**Logcat**

```
05-05 16:38:06.584 7111-7334/com.example.thiago.myapplication I/System.out: Tentando logar em http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/logins?fields=email%2Cpassword&filter=id%20%3D%201
05-05 16:38:06.614 7111-7334/com.example.thiago.myapplication I/System.out: Connected
05-05 16:38:06.914 7111-7334/com.example.thiago.myapplication I/System.out: After This Connection
05-05 16:38:06.914 7111-7334/com.example.thiago.myapplication I/System.out: {"resource":[{"email":"thiago@gmail.com","password":"1234"}]}
05-05 16:38:06.924 7111-7111/com.example.thiago.myapplication I/System.out: chegou até aqui1
05-05 16:38:06.924 7111-7111/com.example.thiago.myapplication W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for email
05-05 16:38:06.924 7111-7111/com.example.thiago.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
05-05 16:38:06.924 7111-7111/com.example.thiago.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
05-05 16:38:06.924 7111-7111/com.example.thiago.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.thiago.myapplication.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:179)
05-05 16:38:06.924 7111-7111/com.example.thiago.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.thiago.myapplication.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:98)
05-05 16:38:06.924 7111-7111/com.example.thiago.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
```

**AsyncTask**

```
 private class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;
        //private final String mCep;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;


        }

        @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... String) {

            HttpURLConnection httpCon = null;

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
          //  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"No começo de doInbackground....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              int id = 1;

            try {

                //URL url = new URL("https://viacep.com.br/ws/05508030/json/");
                String urlLogin = "http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/logins?fields=email%2Cpassword&filter=id%20%3D%20"+id;

                //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Tentando logar....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Tentando logar em "+ urlLogin);

                URL url = new URL(urlLogin);
                httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                //httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpCon.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                httpCon.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.fl_vmD9mHStS8o6U_WPau2Ll7QJkNbcJQaFLFwuMvGQ");
                httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic  dGhpYWdvLmNhbWFyZ29AZXZvbHV0aW9uaXQuY29tLmJyOmluaWNpYWwyMDE3");
                System.out.println("Connected");


                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpCon.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                    System.out.println("After This Connection");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                httpCon.disconnect();
            }
            System.out.println(result.toString());

            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            /*mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                finish();
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }*/


            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(result);
                System.out.println("chegou até aqui1");

                String mEmail = json.getString("email");
                String mPassword = json.getString("password");

                System.out.println("Email: "+ mEmail);
                System.out.println("Senha: "+ mPassword);
                System.out.println("chegou até aqui2");
                if (mEmail.equals(email) && mPassword.equals(password)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("result", result);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                else {
                    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Email ou senha inválido(s)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("Email ou senha inválido(s)");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             //    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            //  intent.putExtra("result", result);
           //    startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your json output looks like this.

```
        {"resource":[{"email":"thiago@gmail.com","password":"1234"}]}
```

error message says `'org.json.JSONException: No value for email'` thats because you were trying to read **email** value directly from the **json object**. in order to read the **email and string** value you need to read the **resource** which is an array then **iterate the array** and then read the **email** and **string** value.

```
JSONObject json = null;
try {
    json = new JSONObject(result);
    System.out.println("chegou até aqui1");
    //new code reading json
   JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("resource");

   for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String mEmail = json_data.getString("email");
        String mPassword = json_data.getString("password");

        System.out.println("Email: "+ mEmail);
        System.out.println("Senha: "+ mPassword);

       );
    //end....

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```